# Doing double cell reference in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, reference, cells

I am writing a sheet to display a specific students' results on a test. In a seperate sheet I have all the results of all the students and want to make some graphics for just this one student, which is given by his row number in the matrix of results.

To get this done, I need to do a reference inside a reference, and I dont know how to do that. A typical script in a cell will be:

```
=IF('All results'!G3>=E3*'All results'!G2;3;IF('All results'!G3>=E4*'All results'!G2;2;1))
```

Here, I need the '3' after G to be extracted from an other cell (given in B5 in the current sheet).

How can I place a reference inside a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you are wanting.

I think you want a way to build the reference 'All results'!G3, where the 3 is a variable and its value is located in cell B5.  To do that, you can use the `ADDRESS` function:

```
=ADDRESS(B5,7,,,"All Results")
```

The '7' in the formula specifies the 7th column, which is 'G'.

You would then use the `INDIRECT` function to retrieve the value in the cell that was returned by the `ADDRESS` function.